# How to overlay video view over android camera preview?

Tags: android, video, android-camera

I have tried a lots of things for playing a video over a camera preview but have had no luck. The video is playing but it is in the background of the camera preview. Can anyone tell me how to do this? I am using android api 10 and samsung galaxy s2(os-2.3.3).
When I tried the same on samsung galaxy-Y (os-2.3.6) it works fine, so my question is that what is the right way to do this and why does it works on galaxy-Y and not on galaxy s2.